# how to redirect a squarespace page url to a non-squarespace subdomain

Tags: redirect, subdomain, squarespace

I host my website on Squarespace. Recently moved my job board from [www.xyz.com/jobs](http://www.xyz.com/jobs) to jobs.xyz.com

When I google my website name, it still reflects the old page xyz.com/jobs and I was hoping to re-direct the traffic to the new subdomain while continuing to use Squarespace.

Any inputs/thoughts on how can I go about it?

Thanks
Deep

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that. Open Settings -> Advanced -> URL Mapping and add the line example:

```
/jobs -> https://jobs.xyz.com 301
```

The thing is, probably right after you save it, it will be corrected to:

```
/jobs -> /https://jobs.xyz.com 301
```

With a slash before https, probably because of some autocorrect built-in. So open these settings again and remove that slash, then save again.

It worked for me though people say it's impossible, here's the proof:
https://asmodeoux.squarespace.com/changelog/android